# CSS background image cover

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to understand why I am unable to get the `background-cover` property to work inside of my `div`?

```css
.box {
  height: 240px;
  width: 31.1111%;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  margin: 1.11111%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.15);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background:url('http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png');">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="buttonContainer">
      <button>preview</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, first of all you have invalid html. You are missing `</div>`.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are having?

Comment: Second of all: Define "properly". What do you want to happen? This question is not really answerable without that information. I cannot go inside your head and guess what you want to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline styling has a [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Therefore `background` is overwriting the property [shorthand `background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Background_Properties).

Change `background` to `background-image`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/008f5yjb/)

```
<div class="box" style="background-image:url('http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png');">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <button>preview</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After looking at the example, it seems like you may be more interested in using the value `contain` rather than `cover`. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/oefmfc97/)

Answer (score 1):

`background` is a **general** property, so this includes: `backgound-image`, `background-size`, `background-color`, `background-position`, etc.

So **you should to use** in this case `background-image` only, because `background` is overwriting your above css defined properties.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you change `background` to `background-image` see working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3t7ftpky/

**Why does this work?**

`background` is a shorthand property and by putting it inline it overrides the other `background-size` properties in the stylesheet. you can find out more about the [css background property here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background):